# C++ String class

Tags: c++, performance, strings, reinventing-the-wheel, memory-management

I made a string class to be used as a replacement for `std::string`. It has all the find functions (`find`, `rfind`, `find_first_of`, ...), basic iterators (just `begin` and `end`, no reverse iterators), almost all the operators (`+`, `+=`, `==`, `[]`, `<<`), an insert, erase and substring function, `c_str()`, and it is dynamic.

It is mostly faster than `std::string`. It allocates the characters on the heap (`malloc`, `realloc`, `free`), and it shouldn't have any undefined behaviour.

I have to know if the memory management is optimal or if some undefined behaviour is present.

**String.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

class String
{
private:
    char* str;
    size_t length;
    size_t capacity;

public:
    typedef char* iterator;

    const short int npos = -1;

    String(int size = 0)
    {
        length = 0;
        capacity = size;
        str = (char*)malloc((capacity + 1) * sizeof(char));
    };

    String(char* string)
    {
        length = strlen(string);
        capacity = length;
        str = (char*)malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
        memcpy(str, string, (length + 1) * sizeof(char));
    }

    String(const String &string)
    {
        str = (char*)malloc((string.length + 1) * sizeof(char));
        length = string.length;
        capacity = string.capacity;
        memcpy(str, string.str, length * sizeof(char));
    }

    ~String()
    {
        free(str);
    }

    const char* begin()
    {
        return str;
    }

    const char* end()
    {
        return str+length;
    }

    char front()
    {
        return *str;
    }

    char back()
    {
        return str[length];
    }

    char& operator[](int n)
    {
        return str[n];
    }

    friend String& operator+(String lhs, String &rhs)
    {
        lhs += rhs;
        return lhs;
    }

    String& operator+=(String &right)
    {
        *this += right.str;
        return *this;
    }

    String& operator+=(char* right)
    {
        size_t toAdd = strlen(right);
        if (length + toAdd > capacity)
        {
            while (length + toAdd > capacity)
            {
                if (capacity == 0)
                    capacity = 1;
                capacity *= 2;
            }
            str = (char*)realloc(str, (capacity + 1) * sizeof(char));
        }
        memcpy(str + length, right, toAdd * sizeof(char));
        length += toAdd;
        str[length] = 0;
        return *this;
    }

    String& operator+=(char right)
    {
        if (length + 1 > capacity)
        {
            while (length + 1 > capacity)
            {
                if (capacity == 0)
                    capacity = 1;
                capacity *= 2;
            }
            str = (char*)realloc(str, (capacity + 1) * sizeof(char));
        }
        str[length++] = right;
        str[length] = 0;
        return *this;
    }

    String& operator=(char* right)
    {
        length = strlen(right);
        size_t prevCap = capacity;
        while (length + 1 > capacity)
        {
            if (capacity == 0)
                capacity = 1;
            capacity *= 2;
        }
        if (capacity != prevCap)
            str = (char*)realloc(str, (capacity + 1) * sizeof(char));
        memcpy(str, right, (length + 1) * sizeof(char));
        return *this;
    }

    String& operator=(String &right)
    {
        *this = right.str;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(String &right)
    {
        return strcmp(str, right.str) == 0;
    }

    int find(char* string)
    {
        size_t wordLength = strlen(string);
        if (wordLength > length)
            return npos;

        bool match;

        for (int i = 0; i < length-wordLength; i++)
        {
            match = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; j++)
            {
                if (str[i + j] != string[j])
                {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (match)
                return i;
        }
        return npos;
    }

    int rfind(char* string)
    {
        size_t wordLength = strlen(string);
        if (wordLength > length)
            return npos;

        bool match;

        for (int i = length-1; i >= wordLength; i--)
        {
            match = true;
            for (int j = wordLength-1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (str[i + j] != string[j])
                {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (match)
                return i;
        }
        return npos;
    }

    int find_first_of(char* string)
    {
        size_t wordLength = strlen(string);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            char c = str[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; j++)
            {
                if (c == string[j])
                    return i;
            }
        }
        return npos;
    }

    int find_last_of(char* string)
    {
        size_t wordLength = strlen(string);

        for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            char c = str[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; j++)
            {
                if (c == string[j])
                    return i;
            }
        }
        return npos;
    }

    int find_first_not_of(char* string)
    {
        size_t wordLength = strlen(string);

        bool different;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            char c = str[i];
            different = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; j++)
            {
                if (c == string[j])
                {
                    different = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (different)
                return i;
        }
        return npos;
    }

    int find_last_not_of(char* string)
    {
        size_t wordLength = strlen(string);

        bool different;

        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            char c = str[i]; 
            different = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; j++)
            {
                if (c == string[j])
                {
                    different = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (different)
                return i;
        }
        return npos;
    }

    String substr(int offset, size_t count = -1)
    {
        if (count == -1)
            count = length - offset;
        char* sub = (char*)_alloca(count * sizeof(char));
        memcpy(sub, str + offset, count * sizeof(char));
        sub[count] = 0;

        return String(sub);
    }

    void assign(iterator begin, iterator end)
    {
        length = end - begin; 
        if (length > capacity)
        {
            while (length > capacity)
            {
                if (capacity == 0)
                    capacity = 1;
                capacity *= 2;
            }
            str = (char*)realloc(str, (capacity + 1) * sizeof(char));
        }
        memcpy(str, begin, length * sizeof(char));
        str[length] = 0;
    }

    void insert(int pos, char* toInsert)
    {
        int toAdd = strlen(toInsert);
        if (length + toAdd > capacity)
        {
            while (length + toAdd > capacity)
            {
                if (capacity == 0)
                    capacity = 1;
                capacity *= 2;
            }
            str = (char*)realloc(str, (capacity + 1) * sizeof(char));
        }
        memmove(str + pos + toAdd, str + pos, (length - pos) * sizeof(char));
        memcpy(str + pos, toInsert, toAdd * sizeof(char));
        length += toAdd;
        str[length] = 0;
    }

    void erase(int pos, size_t count)
    {
        length -= count;
        memmove(str + pos, str + pos + count, (length - pos) * sizeof(char));
        str[length] = 0;
    }

    void pop_back()
    {
        str[--length] = 0;
    }

    const char* c_str()
    {
        return str;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, String &str)
    {
        os << str.str;
        return os;
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't really know what you want people to review really, but I'd suggest you stick to using `std::string` if you actually plan on replacing it with this implementation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what reason is there for the average programmer to use your class instead of the `std::basic_string` template?  If they need, say, wide characters, UTF-16, or UTF-32, they have to stick with one of the standard strings anyways.  And even if they just need ASCII or UTF-8, `std::string` is so common that using a string type that isn't compatible with it all but guarantees that their code won't be easy to integrate with any existing code, unless the entire code base is designed around `String` and doesn't depend on any external code that uses `std::string`.

Comment: I also noticed that your `npos` is a `short` instead of a `size_t`, there's no member functions `data()`, `size()`, `length()`, `max_size()`, `resize()`, `capacity()`, `reserve()`, `clear()`, `empty()`, `shrink_to_fit()`, `at()`, `append()`, `push_back()`, `replace()`, `swap()`, `get_allocator()`, `copy()`, or `compare()`.  You're also missing some of the non-member functions, and all but one of the member typedefs.  Any templated code that takes your `String` and expects the generic, standard interface is in for a treat.

Comment: Also, `alloca()` and its other variants are non-standard, and kinda platform-specific, so it's probably best to use some preprocessor `#if` magic to make sure you get the right one (and provide an alternative for platforms that don't have a version of it).

Comment: And that's my two cents.  Not sure of myself enough to make that an outright answer, but it just looks a bit fishy to me.

Comment: take a look at fbstring (string class implementation of facebook folly library), they say it's faster than std::string. [fbstring](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/FBString.h)

Comment: @chedynajjar The scale of facebook and your project are slightly different, a 1% performance gain for facebook can be millions of dollars annually in utility costs. While for your run of the mill project 1% will not matter in the least. Also their string appears to be reference counted so it has different semantics to `std::string` and I only skimmed it briefly but it looks like it has COW optimisation too which is prohibited by C++11 standard. At any rate the performance of the string class will probably not affect your application in any way either, unless all you do is string processing.

Comment: There is no way this is faster than `std::string`. There are several obvious optimizations that are not done here. Also at least one place in this code where non optimal implementation is used. Please back up that claim with proof.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You claim that your `String` is faster than `std::string` I do not believe this claim. Please post your benchmark code.

`std::string` often has [Small String Optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring) to avoid dynamic memory allocation when used on small strings which is fairly common.

Your code is not [const correct](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness). For example:

```
const char* c_str()
```

should be:

```
const char* c_str() const
```

and:

```
bool operator==(String &right)
```

should be:

```
bool operator==(const String &right) const
```

This is not the correct signature for `operator +`:

```
friend String& operator+(String lhs, String &rhs)
```

because it allows the following to compile:

```
String a,b;
a + b = "foo";
```

It should be:

```
friend String operator+(const String& lhs, const String& rhs)
```

Do not repeat yourself, your copy constructor and assignment operator share a lot of code. You can implement copy constructor like this:

```
String(const String& s)
    : String() // Initialise to empty string
{
    *this = s;
}
```

You should also implement move constructor and move assignment operator.

You should also used `std::vector<char>` as the backing store, this way you don't need the `size` or `capacity` members. Your code will simplify a lot and you will not need to worry about manually keeping track of the memory. Using `malloc/free` in a C++ program is a code smell.

But all in all, the above is pretty pointless because you really should use `std::string` and save yourself the trouble of maintaining and coding your own string class.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you use `malloc` and `free` in a C++ program? Plus you do not handle any bad allocation errors on the heap which may lead to a dangling pointer (comapre [std::bad_alloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc)).

```
capacity = size;
// if the allocation fails str points to corrupted memory
str = (char*)malloc((capacity + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

And you adjust the capacity of the string even in case the allocation failed.

Comment: I use it because i need realloc too

Comment: @DanDan Why do you need to use `realloc`?